# This site can’t be reached in aws public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Facing the problem with AWS EC2 public IP. Earlier it was working fine after restart instance it stopped.

Then I update the public IP of DNS but still not working. I am able to ping the domain, as well as the public IP, Both are working fine.

**Ping Detail:**

[image: aws public ip and domain ping]

I did not make any changes in Security Group Inbound and it's all fine.

**Security Group Inbound:**

[image: aws ec2 secutiry group inbound]

Comment: If you Stopped and Started the instance, it might have received a different IP address, so check that first. Try connecting using the IP address rather than the DNS Name, just in case the value is cached. Are you able to SSH into the instance? If so, login and try `curl localhost` to see whether the web server is responding.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein I got this message after run command on SSH
"curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused"

Comment: Did you run that command on the server itself? If so, it indicates that the web server is not running on port 80. (Although that would normally result in a Timeout, rather than Connection Refused.) You should check whether the application / web server is running.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein   My apache was stopped I run restart it and the website start working. I used this command to restart it "sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart"

Answer (score 0):

A good check is to login to the server and run:

```
curl localhost
```

If that doesn't work, then it indicates that the web server / application isn't running.

If it *does* work, then the problem might lie with network settings (eg Security Group).